# Unable to run docker IIS windows container

Tags: asp.net, docker, powershell, iis, .net-4.7.2

I am new to docker and trying to run legacy .NET applications inside a windows container (using docker desktop). Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]

RUN dism.exe /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:iis-webserver /NoRestart

#Configure IIS

RUN Import-Module WebAdministration;New-Item –Path IIS:\AppPools\CustomApppool
RUN C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set apppool /apppool.name:CustomApppool /processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /processModel.username:us\user1 /processModel.password:P@@Ss

RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-Windows-Auth;
RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-IP-Security;
RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45;
RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-Dyn-Compression;
RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-Scripting-Tools;
RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-AppInit;
RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-Http-Redirect;
RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-WebSockets;

# Update permissions on website folder
RUN icacls 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot' /Grant 'IUSR:(OI)(CI)(RX)'
RUN icacls 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot' /Grant 'IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool:(OI)(CI)(RX)'
RUN icacls 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot' /Grant 'IIS AppPool\CustomApppool:(OI)(CI)(RX)'

#Copy website files from App host folder to container wwwroot folder
COPY Admin/ "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/Admin"
COPY Sade/ "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/Sade"
COPY Rater/ "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/Rater"

#Copy Service Monitor file
COPY ServiceMonitor.exe C:/

RUN New-WebApplication -Name Admin -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Admin -ApplicationPool CustomApppool;
RUN New-WebApplication -Name Sade -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Sade -ApplicationPool CustomApppool;
RUN New-WebApplication -Name Rater -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Rater -ApplicationPool CustomApppool;

#Authentication Settings
# Enable Directory browsing
RUN C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config 'Default Web Site' /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:'True'

# Enable anonymous authentication
RUN Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter '/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication' -Location 'Default Web Site' -Name enabled -Value True;

# Enable basic authentication
#RUN Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter '/system.webServer/security/authentication/basicAuthentication' -Location 'Default Web Site' -Name enabled -Value True;

# Enable Windows authentication
RUN Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter '/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication' -Location 'Default Web Site' -Name Enabled -Value False;

RUN Restart-Service W3SVC

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ['C:\ServiceMonitor.exe','w3svc']
```

I am able to build the image by running `docker build -t demo/site`
I am running this command to start the container `docker run -p 8000:80 demo/site:latest` but i am getting this error:

```
At line:1 char:35
+ $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; ['C:\ServiceMonitor.exe','w3svc']
+                                   ~
Missing type name after '['.
At line:1 char:58
+ $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; ['C:\ServiceMonitor.exe','w3svc']
+                                                          ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingTypename
```

Please, what am i missing? What do i need to do to get the container to start, and to be able to browse my website on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your single quotes on the last line with double quotes.
Also try replacing ENTRYPOINT with CMD as well.

Comment: Consider adding an example of your fix so OP can try it out

Answer (score 0):

Docker file on Windows Containers is picky about how you escape strings.

The issue you are seeing is clearly a combination of the overriden SHELL and then the ENTRYPOINT.

Try using CMD instead of ENTRYPOINT:

```
CMD ["C:\ServiceMonitor.exe","w3svc"]
```

Also, restore your SHELL after the setup and before the entrypoint:

```
SHELL ["cmd.exe"]
CMD ["C:\ServiceMonitor.exe","w3svc"]
```

You can find an example working dockerfile for IIS here:

https://github.com/david-garcia-garcia/windowscontainers/blob/master/servercore2022iis/dockerfile

This one sits on top of this other image which actually handles the entrypoint/shell/cmd configuration:

https://github.com/david-garcia-garcia/windowscontainers/blob/master/servercore2022/dockerfile

I would advise against using service monitor, you are better of with an endless loop powershell entrypoint, and doing proper health checks if this is going to be K8S/AKS.

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

SHELL ["powershell.exe"]

##### YOUR SETUP SCRIPT

CMD ["powershell.exe", "-File", "C:\\entrypoint\\entrypoint.ps1" ]
```